# How to stop Whatsapp Desktop from auto updating

Tags: whatsapp, auto-updates

Hi I have installed WhatsApp desktop for MacOS it tries to pull 200|300mb updates everyday which is annoying, so I need to stop it from that.

Had already tried looking into the app to find a separate auto updater to delete but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Handsoff` I found what is the request and it goes through `*.fbcdn.net` it is pretty easy to block that, however not possible natively.

You need to first install `dnsmasq` like : https://gist.github.com/ogrrd/5831371

in the config at `$(brew --prefix)/etc/dnsmasq.conf` use :

```
address=/.fbcdn.net/127.0.0.1
```

and for the resolver at `/etc/resolver/fbcdn.net` use :

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Run `scutil --dns` to see the resolver.

Run `sudo brew services start dnsmasq` to start the dns server

test it via :

```bsh
ping test.fbcdn.net
PING test.fbcdn.net (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.349 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.444 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The old Whatsapp desktop app is based on Electron (a framework that combines chrome with web technology to more easily deliver webapps that feel native).

You can change permissions on the app file or executable to attempt to break auto-updating.  On macos, using the finder's inspector, you can "lock" the app.

This will break auto-updates but you will still eventually face non-stop popups to enter your password to allow the update.

Under the hood many Electron apps use Squirrel for updating.  You can disable squirrel with an [environment variable apparently](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Mac/blob/bde5ff2983e91e7310c4139223ed04870e14a5b1/Squirrel/SQRLUpdater.m#L175).

e.g. starting whatsapp binary from terminal with something like:

```bash
DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/MacOS/WhatsApp
```

Indeed the Squirrel popups to enter your password to allow installation of an update helper go away.

...however you may still get faced with a "Updating whatsapp..." screen that never goes away after you disable Squirrel.

Digging around it looks like Whatsapp is using an expiration timestamp in a dom element to determine when it should check for updates.  I couldn't find any ENV I could easily tweak to disable the update process.

You can use [`electron_inject`](https://github.com/tintinweb/electron-inject) (a python project) in order to tweak how the app runs a bit.

```bash
pip3 install electron_inject
```

In particular you can inject custom scripts to run within the Electron app and attach devtools debugger to figure out what is going on.

For instance you can save the following as `whatsapp-inject.js`

```javascript
function initPostDom () {
    var expiresEl = document.getElementById('hard_expire_time');
    expiresEl.dataset.time = ""+(Date.now()/1000 + 24*60*60*7);  // 7 days from now 
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initPostDom);
```

And then run Whatsapp using `electron_inject` like so:

```bash
DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=1 python3 -m electron_inject -t 5 -r whatsapp-inject.js -  /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/MacOS/WhatsApp
```

Assuming you've changed filesystem permissions to block auto-update, then running Whatsapp this way does the following 2 things:

- disables Squirrel updater which removes the "enter password to install" popups.
- tells whatsapp not to try and update for another 7 days.  If you don't restart whatsapp within a week you may see some update stuff.

On windows, should be the same, just replace `/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/MacOS/WhatsApp` with the path to your Whatsapp `.exe`.

No telling how long this will work or if you are on a different version.  Tested on macos version `2.2349.51`.

I'm running unsupported macos (big sur) for specific reasons and the autoupdater replaced my app with one that won't even start on big sur.  Then there is the from the ground up app they are trying to push everyone to.  I tried it and hated it.  Lots of terrible UX in the new app and missing features...so I'm holding off as long as I can.  Hopefully they will fix the new app UX and missing features before the APIs the old app talks to are killed.

If you want to dig around yourself, you can get into devtools by adding the `-b` flag when running electron_inject.  You can play around with things like intercepting `fetch` responses from your injected script.  Take a look at `killswitch` and `check-update` calls.  FWIW, intercepting these and overriding the responses didn't seem to help with disabling updates.

If you want to dig around the source on disk, you can do the following to ex

```bash
npx @electron/asar extract /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar /tmp/whatsapp-app-asar
```

Answer (score -1):

After tweaking for a few hours I found a perfect working solution

1. download the last working "old" WhatsApp version 2.2349.51 from here https://whatsapp-desktop.en.uptodown.com/mac/versions
2. install it but don't start it
3. disable Squirrel updates (WhatsApp being an atom application relies on it)

`/bin/launchctl setenv DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK 1`

4. extract the source code

`npx @electron/asar extract /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar ~/whatsapp-app-asar`

5. modify in *~/whatsapp-app-asar/index.html* the *hard_expire_time* *data-time epoch* to the year 2099

`<div id="hard_expire_time" data-time="4074711589"></div>`

6. pack back the source code

`npx @electron/asar pack whatsapp-app-asar app.asar`

7. replace the app.asar in */Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Resources* with our new modified